# Conditional htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I just want some help with my .htaccess configuration. Before I have this problem where I need to redirect the page to
a specific url. Like if the user type http://mydomain/test it will be redirected to http://mydomain/app/r/test. I
achieved the redirection using .htaccess. The code is below

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule (.*) http://mydomain/app/r/$1 [R=301,L]
```

But I have this new specification. As follows:

> If user visit http://mydomain/ or http://domain/index.php, he will be
>   redirected to http://mydomain/mymanager
>
> If user visit
>   http://mydomain/{any_segment}, he will be redirected to
>   http://mydomain/app/r/{any_segment}

Here is my current htaccess. Basically in the url, any characters will be redirected to ***/app/r/{}*** except ***index.php***. But what about the http://domain/? How can I achieve this.

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mydomain$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.mydomain$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index.php
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://mydomain/app/r/$1 [R=301,L]
```

I've been playing around my htaccess and any pointers will be of great help to me.

Comment: Your current htaccess will result in infinite loop, unless there is more to it (or in server config files) that you are not showing us

Comment: Are you sure you are redirecting to same same domain as the original request? If yes then it will cause a redirect loop as @DusanBajic commented.

Comment: i dont understand but inside my index.php, there's a code there to redirect to mymanager (eg header('Location: /mymanager')). I dont have any more config files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are your rules :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mydomain$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.mydomain$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index.php
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://mydomain/app/r/$1 [R=301,L]
```

It looks like , any request should redirect to `/app/r/` except A URI start with `/index.php` but still not doing that , in normal cases , so you should exclude the target directory from being redirect again and again by this rule `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://mydomain/app/r/$1 [R=301,L]`  , `^(.*)$` means any URI start with any thing and the server will look, if there is a condition , and actually there is only one condition to exclude `index.php`, otherwise redirect .

So , you should exclude this target directory along with `index.php` like this :

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^(/index\.php|/app/r/)
```

But still you want to match a request that target HOST only so,you should add that as well :

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^(/index\.php|/app/r/|/?$)
```

Then you could match host with www or non-www like this :

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?mydomain$
```

Your rules should look like this :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?mydomain$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^(/index\.php|/app/r/|/?$)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://mydomain/app/r/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Also you could summarize that more by utilizing `%{REQUEST_URI}` like this :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?mydomain$
RewriteRule !^(index\.php|app/r/|/?$) http://mydomain/app/r%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

**NOTE:** Clear browser cache then test

Comment: i know this is probably not with the topic. Is it much better or good practice if I add the redirect inside my htaccess too? Right now my domain host or index.php has a redirect code to mydomain/mymanager.

Comment: @WonderingCoder in term of performance , if you able to add any rule inside server config file that is better than .htaccess